# Windows inserting unknown characters. Displaying in Linux bash as ^?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, atom-editor

Hi there I have looked extensively for this. I am using Atom editor and Sublime text on Windows. Both are inserting unknown characters everywhere when saving. Usually in unedited spots of code.

The characters are showing up as ^?

This is causing build problems in the Linux bash in Windows ie

```
  error  Parsing error: Unexpected character ''
```

I have tried everything including changing the encoding from utf-8.

Any ideas please ?

Comment: Try running `sed -i 's/\r$//' myfile` and see if that changes anything

Comment: They appear anywhere, where a space has been entered, not necessarily new lines. Editor is set to linux new lines. 

it appears like this still randomly after each save

            "}^?"

Comment: after running sed -i 's/\r$//' file.js

Comment: Try printing the file with `LC_ALL=C cat -vet /path/to/file` -- that'll convert all of the various invisible and/or weird characters to something visible and decodable. Note that it's normal for lines to end with `$` in this mode -- that's how it shows the newline character. If you add examples of what the weird characters look like in this mode, we'll be able to make much better guesses about what they are and where they came from.

Comment: The last command added $ characters everywhere. it seems around newlines. The editor is set to unix newlines.

Answer (score 1):

^? is a DEL character
Its hex value is 7F
a Question mark (?) is 3F in hex
The Ctrl (Contol) key toggles the 0x40 bit so ^? (Ctrl-question)
is 0x7f

It is also 177 octal.  That is for the 'tr' command below.

```
   `tr -d 177 <file_with_del_characters >file_without_del_chars`
```

Should give you what you asked for.

Comment: This is a problem too unfortunately. 

js: Unexpected token (123:37) Use --force to continue.

I believe it removed all references to 1 also especially if it contained if else like  ? 1 : 0

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the `dos2unix` command. This command removes hidden windows characters from your file.

```
dos2unix /path/to/file
```

Comment: I tried to consult Atom editor of a problem but they ignored me and other editors are doing it too.

I press control-s to save and I believe this partially causes it. I tried setting different encodings too.

Comment: It is quite possibly also happening because of control shortcuts like control-s , control-c, control-v.